# Labeling points with polygon they overlay using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, point

I have a shapefile of a cut-up map of England. I have overlaid points (lat/long) from a CSV as a separate layer.

Is there a way to output what polygon each point is on. So, i'd want to be able to output that point A,B,C are on Polygon 1, D,E,F is polygon 2 etc.

I've counted how many points per polygon but I do not know how to do to swing it back round so it tells me what polygon each point overlays.

Answer (score 0):

**Vector > Data Management Tools > Join attributes by location**

Target vector layer = `points`
Join vector layer = `polygons`
Geometric predicate = `within`

Leave the rest on their defaults and run it. The output points layer will have a new field in the table referring to the underlying polygon, and you can set the labels to refer to it.

I'm certain there's a more elegant solution involving an expression or bit of code, but this will certainly work, provided your points layer is static.

Comment: Thanks, Josh. I did google around but wasn't completely sure what was the right answer! The process you suggested worked perfectly. Thanks very much for replying.